# initialise an array with user input

Tags: arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I am using Visual Studio 2013, c++, console application. I have been struggling with a question for quite some time now. I want to know if there is a way to initialise an array, with input from the user, for example:

I have an array: `int arr[] = { 3, 7, 5, 9, 1};`. Therefore, I want the initialised values to be a user input.

Is there a way I can do it? All help and comments will be appreciated.

This is my code:
cout << "Enter the number of array elements: ";
    cin >> elements;

```
cout << "Enter the difference value: ";
cin >> difference;

cout << "Enter the sequence of elements:  ";

vector<int> arr(elements);


for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];

}
//the following needs to have an array
//in their respective functions.
sorter(arr[], elements);
elementsDifference(arr[], elements, difference);
```

this program has to loop through an array and find pairs with the given difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
int arr[10] , i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) 
   std::cin >> a[i];
```

This simple code fragment will take 10 inputs from the user and store them in the array.

If you want to change the number of input, you can just change the condition in the for loop ( also make sure that your array has enough size to store all the values ).

## UPDATE

You can try it like this

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int a[size],i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
  cin >> a[i];
for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
  cout << a[i] << endl;
```

Normally, people would just make the size of the array very large ( like `a[100000]` or so ) and then accept the size, and fill up the array using a code similar to the one I gave above.

But an even better way would be to use `vector` . You should learn about using `vector`

Comment: But, in my question, the size of the array depends on the input by the user, such as, Enter the size of elements:  and the user then inputs the number of elements, how would that work? @Arun A.S

Answer (score 0):

If you need a variable-length array in C++, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> ints;
ints.reserve(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Enter element #" << i + 1 << ": ";
    int element;
    std::cin >> element;
    ints.push_back(element);
}
```

Comment: I did try it, but no luck, here is my code, it may help in explaining what I'm actually looking for:

Comment: cout << "Enter the number of array elements: ";
 cin >> elements;

 cout << "Enter the difference value: ";
 cin >> difference;
 
 cout << "Enter the sequence of elements:  ";

 vector<int> arr(elements);
 

 for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
 {
  cin >> arr[i]; // this is where I need to enter the sequence of numbers
  
 }
 //the following needs to have an array
 //in their respective functions.
 sorter(arr[], elements);
 elementsDifference(arr[], elements, difference);

Comment: You can get the underlying array from the vector with `arr.data()`, or `&arr[0]` without C++11 support. E.g. `sorter(arr.data(), elements)`.

Answer (score -4):

#include

int main()
{

```
char ch;
std::cout << "Enter the size of the array\n";
std::cin >> ch;
std::cout<<"Enter the numbers you want in the array\n";
switch (ch) {
case '1': { int arr[1]; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (i = 0;i < 1;++i)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];break;
}
case '2': { int arr[2]; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (i = 0;i < 2;++i)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];break;
}
case '3': { int arr[3]; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (i = 0;i < 3;++i)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];break;
}
case '4': { int arr[4]; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (i = 0;i < 4;++i)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];break;
}

        
}
```

}// etc...

Comment: This is just an example of bad code. Don't do like this